# Is it possible to apply an alternating row background to a table-stroke in jquery mobile ?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to show classic grid data in a form way. So for instance:

From (layout A):

Col A     Col B     Col C

Value 1   Value 2   Value 3

To (**layout B**):

Col A: Value 1

Col B: Value 2

Col C: Value 3

I'm developing an asp.net application with jquery mobile and i know i can create a grid with class **table-stroke** that  automatically reflow my grid as shown in layout B.

What i'm trying to do is to 'alternate' color background for each row. But it seems it not works as i want. 
When reflowed, it colorize:

Col A:...   <- background White

Col B:...   <- Background Gray

Col C:...   <- background White

Instead, i want "Record 1" (all columns A,B,C..) color White, then, "Record 2" (all columns) color Gray..

I've used this:

```
/* Add alternating row stripes */
.table-stroke tbody tr:nth-child(odd) td,
.table-stroke tbody tr:nth-child(odd) th {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

Anyway, is there any better solutions to show data for small screen from a grid to a form style ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try the jQM class table-stripe as well as table-stroke: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/upsnacbt/?

Comment: No i didn't try... thank you very much, your answer solved my problem!